How to create a MLClient in azure machine learning pipeline python step?
I want to register a folder which contains PKL files as one model into model registry.
It is easy for me to use MLClient to achieve the goal like:
model = Model(
     path = model_output_path,
     type = AssetTypes.CUSTOM_MODEL,
     name = MODEL_COLLECTION_NAME,
     description = 'This is a collection of peakload models for different APIs.'
 )

model = ml_client.models.create_or_update(model)

But, the initialization of mlclient with DefaultAzureCredential failed in the pipeline step after training finished, so it seems I can not use a MLClient straightly there.
However, it is strange to me that with mlflow, I can straightly register models.
mlflow.register(XXX)

So, it must be a credential somewhere prepared somewhere for mlflow client.
Why the mlclient can not be authorized with the same credential used by mlflow?
How can I achieve that? Because the pipeline is just correlated to the workspace, why should I do auth again from the pipeline to workspace?
And, it I can not do that. How can I register a folder as a model into the model registry?

a solution that use mlclient with some default credential in a AML pipeline step.
a solution that help me to register a folder as one model into model registry?


Are you using managed identity when running pipeline as a authorization?

Thanks for your response. I am not sure about it as I did not do any special settings to run the pipeline. Everything is default. I believe the auth between pipeline and workspace is managed by AML team which is hided to me.

Then you need to check with that team. whether they are using managed identity or service principal for authorization.

Thanks for your help! I will try to contact the team.
